# Is there a high quality Q&A (clone of stackoverflow) that integrates with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013

Is there a high quality Q&A (clone of stackoverflow) that integrates well with SharePoint 2013?

I don't believe that SP13's community can be retro-fitted for our needs (my apologies but couldnt find tags for QA here)

Comment: so are you looking for a place where someone can ask a question and someone else can answer it? With all the neat features this site has? rating, follow, etc?

Comment: Dicussion Boards are the closest thing OOTB (and you can customize them pretty close), but I agree with the idea on having a high-class Q&A feature available.

Comment: David Lozzi- exactly. We are leveraging SharePoint for a bunch of features, but see that Q&A that SO/ quora is crucial as most knowledge isn't and never will get formally documented unless asked for...

Answer (score 3):

Q&A is one of the features of [NewsGator Social Sites](http://www.newsgator.com/products/social-sites.aspx).

(Disclosure: I work for NewsGator)

Comment: +1 I'd vouch for NG. The News Feed's "Ask a Question" feature is what comes to mind here. There aren't reputation points in NG like there are on SO, but there is gamification via badges. As a disclosure, I work for a partner company of NewsGator. Not sure if I need to disclose that or not...

Comment: I beleive there a bunch of gaps in NG (to extent i have seen)... some of them (a) no duplicate match based on Lucerne algo to reduce clutter (b) no tags to ensure experts see their area of expertise (c) points for various actions- very useful in corporate context- can be more than gamification  (d) slick UI

Comment: Finally, pricing of newsgators is also high on per user basis. Hence the qn whether a decent clone (open source or otherwise) that integrates well with SP2013

Answer (score 2):

[Lightning Tools](http://lightningtools.com) has a product called [Social Squared](http://lightningtools.com/products/social-squared/) which is a much richer Q&A forum over the standard discussion boards.  I would assume a 2013 version is in the pipeline. It is being utilized on [NothingButSharePoint](http://nothingbutsharepoint.com) if you want to see a tangible example.